# SQL query issue (sqlbolt.com, ex.10)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I cannot go through one exercise from http://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_with_aggregates
and I cannot go further if I don't complete this.
The problem is ex.10 example two (not aware how to paste a table here):

*For each role, find the average number of years employed by employees in that role*

My attempt is:

```
   /*SELECT max(years_employed) FROM employees;*/
   select role,avg(years_employed) from employees group by role;
```

and imo it does the job but the page does not accept it(the Solution button seems not active). Anyone could help, please?

Comment: I visited the link. Your query is not wrong. Look at the solution given there, they want all the columns to be displayed.

Comment: The requirement of the task is not clear, it's not mentioned that they want all the column, also the query given in the solution will work only in mySQL, in every other RDBMS it will give an error message as every field that is not aggregated need to be in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: I visited the site. the answer they provided itself wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get at least one column value for other columns, you might use the following query:

```
Select role, 
       Min(Name) as Name, 
       Min(Building) as Building, 
       Min(Years_employed) as Years_employed, 
       avg(years_employed) as Average_years_employed  
from employees
Group By role
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT *, avg(years_employed) as average_Year FROM employees GROUP BY role
```

Comment: i don't think your query will work. the columns in select clause should be either in aggregate function or in group by clause